# TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__ python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, devops

run python.py and show this error

```
import boto3, datetime, sys, getopt, re

from operator import itemgetter
from table_logger import TableLogger

class buck: 
    TARIFAWS = 0.023 # 0,023 USD por GB (Primeiros 50 TB por mês)


    counter = 0 

    def __init__(self, s3bucket):
        buck.counter = buck.counter + 1
        self.name = s3bucket.name 
        self.creationdate = s3bucket.creation_date
        self.size = self.metricCloudwatch(s3bucket,"BucketSizeBytes", "StandardStorage")
        self.nbreObj = self.metricCloudwatch(s3bucket,"NumberOfObjects", "AllStorageTypes")
        
        try: 
            boto3.client('s3').get_bucket_encryption(Bucket=s3bucket.name)
            self.number = True
        except:
            self.number = False
        
        self.region = (boto3.client('s3').get_bucket_location(Bucket=s3bucket.name))['LocationConstraint'] 
        
        self.cout = round(self.size / 1024**3 * self.TARIFAWS,2) 
                
        try: 
            boto3.client('s3').get_bucket_replication(Bucket=s3bucket.name)
            self.replica = True
        except:
            self.replica = False

        def collObjInfo(self):
            s3obj = (boto3.client('s3')).list_objects_v2(Bucket=self.name)
            self.lastupdate = None
            self.typeStorage = None
            if s3obj['KeyCount'] != 0:
                self.lastupdate = s3obj['Contents'][0]['LastModified']
                self.typeStorage = s3obj['Contents'][0]['StorageClass']
             
        collObjInfo(self)
        self.public = False 


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__class__) + ": " + str(self.__dict__)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key == 'region':
            return self.region
        if key == 'typeStorage':
            return self.typeStorage

    def getSize(self, human=False): 
        if human:
            return humanReadable(self.size)
        else:
            return self.size

    def metricCloudwatch(self, bucket, nameMetric, storage): 
        cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        try:
            cloudwatch_size = cloudwatch.get_metric_statistics(
                Namespace='AWS/S3',
                MetricName=nameMetric,
                Dimensions=[
                    {'Name': 'BucketName', 'Value': bucket.name},
                    {'Name': 'StorageType', 'Value': storage}
                ],
                Statistics=['Maximum'],
                Period=86400,
                StartTime=(now - datetime.timedelta(days=1)).isoformat(),
                EndTime=now.isoformat()
            )
            if cloudwatch_size["Datapoints"]:
                return cloudwatch_size["Datapoints"][0]['Maximum']
            else:
                return 0
        except:
            return 0
        
def humanReadable(num, suffix='B'): 
    for unit in ['','K','M','G','T','P']:
        if abs(num) < 1024.0:
            return "%3.1f%s%s" % (num, unit, suffix)
        num /= 1024.0
    return "%.1f%s%s" % (num, 'Yi', suffix)

def help(): 
    print("Uso : bucket.py [OPTIONS]")
    print("Exibe informações sobre buckets AWS S3, por padrão")
    print("Argumentos : \n\
    --help \t\t\t ajuda\n\
    --crypted-only \t\t mostra apenas buckets criptografados\n\
    -c, --csv \t\t mostra o resultado em CSV\n\
    -s, --sorted \t\t agrupar resultados por região e grupo de armazenamento\n\
    -h, --human-readable \t exibem tamanhos de 1024\n\
    -f, --filter=filter \t filtra a lista de buckets com base na expressão regular FILTER") 
            

def main():
    
    csv=False
    human = False
    group = False
    filterCrpt = False
    filter = None
    
    try:
        opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "shcf:", ["sorted", "help", "csv", "human-readable", "crypted-only", "filter:"])
    except:
        print("Comando incorreto, aqui está a ajuda: ")
        help()
        sys.exit(2)

    for opts, args in opts:
        if opts == "--help":
            help()
            sys.exit()
        elif opts == "--crypted-only":
            filterCrpt = True
        elif opts in ("-c", "--csv"):
            csv = True
        elif opts in ("-s", "--sorted"):
            group = True
        elif opts in ("-h", "--human-readable"):
            human = True
        elif opts in ("-f", "--filter"):
            if len(args):
                filter = args
            else:
                help()
                sys.exit(2)
        
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucks = [] 

    listeS3Bucks = s3.buckets.all()
    for bucket in listeS3Bucks:
        try:
            if filter:
                re.match(filter,"Test chain")
        except:
            print("Regular expression error")
            sys.exit(2)

        if (filter and re.match(filter,bucket.name)) or not filter:
            try:
                bucks.append(buck(bucket)) 
            except:
                print("Erro ao conectar ao AWS, verifique suas configurações")
                print("Para obter mais informações: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-config-files.html")
                sys.exit(2)

    if group: 
        bucks = sorted(bucks, key=itemgetter('region'))
        bucks = sorted(bucks, key=itemgetter('typeStorage'))
        
    tbl = TableLogger(columns='name,creation date,last update,size,number of objects,number,storage,public,region,cost,replica',
        csv=csv, border=False) 
        
    for cBuck in bucks:
        if (filterCrpt and cBuck.number) or not filterCrpt:
            tbl(cBuck.name, cBuck.creationdate, cBuck.lastupdate, cBuck.getSize(human), str(cBuck.nbreObj), 
            cBuck.number,cBuck.typeStorage, cBuck.public, cBuck.region, "$"+str(cBuck.cout),cBuck.replica)
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

when trying to run the script in python, it gives this error:

TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.**format**
can someone help me? is a script that pulls information from aws s3 bucket.
Bucket is a python script to extract statistics from S3 buckets. It is based on Cloudwatch monitoring metrics.
Help plis

```
 File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\table_logger\table_logger.py", line 203, in __call__
    line = self.format_row(*row_cells)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\table_logger\table_logger.py", line 207, in format_row
    vals = [self.format_column(value, col) for col, value in enumerate(args)]
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\table_logger\table_logger.py", line 207, in <listcomp>
    vals = [self.format_column(value, col) for col, value in enumerate(args)]
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\table_logger\table_logger.py", line 212, in format_column
    return self.formatters[col](value)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\table_logger\fmt.py", line 40, in __call__
    fmt = self.fmt(value)
TypeError: unsupported format string passed to NoneType.__format__
```

Comment: Can you insert the complete error in your question, because to see which line is throwing this error.